# Storage account access from AKS in same region but different subscription/tenant

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-aks, firewall

I'm trying to limit access to a storage account in the *Networking > Firewalls and Virtual Networks* section of a storage account.
I need to whitelist an ASK cluster which is in the same region but it's VNET is not visible to me because I don't have permission to access it's tenant/subscription.

The application from the cluster is connecting to the storage account via the public endpoint.
I've tried whitelisting the cluster's public IP but it didn't work.

Is there a way to whitelist the AKS cluster *using the public endpoint* other than picking *Enabled from all networks*?

Answer (score 1):

I like the option of using an outbound type of nat gateway or some other outbound type option. In the nat gateway example it will snat to the public ip(s) of the nat gateway and you could whitelist that on the storage account.

Another option would be to use Private Endpoints and connect to the storage account via a private ip.